# JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.List out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON below that I'm trying to parse to a POJO using Jackson

```
{
    "Response": {
        "userIds": [
            "http://example.com:10249/User/526241869918679991"
        ],
        "userGroupIds": [
            "http://example.com:10249/UserGroup/1056659494710887089"
        ],
        "accountIds": [
            "http://example.com:10249/ServiceAccount/3354613317986071030"
        ],
        "success": true
    }
}
```

My Response POJO snippet is as below

```
private boolean success;
private List<String> accountIds;
private List<String> userIds;
private List<String> userGroupIds;
```

and their getter and setters

Is my declaration wrong as I'm getting "org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.List out of START_OBJECT token" error on parse"

The parse logic is as below:

```
jsonMapper.readValue(responseJSONString, new TypeReference<List<Response>>() {});
```

Any idea where I'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your input starts with `"Response": ...` which must correspond to a field in some object. So what you have there is a json representation of a `Response` container:

```
class ResponseContainer {
    Response Response;
}
```

Secondly, your try to parse a *list* but your input doesn't start with `[` (which lists should start with) but `{` which indicates that it's an *object*. So if you want it to be a list, wrap the input in `[ ... ]`:

So either change your input to be a list:

```
|
V

[
    {
        "Response": {
            "userIds": [
                "http://example.com:10249/User/526241869918679991"
            ],
            "userGroupIds": [
                "http://example.com:10249/UserGroup/1056659494710887089"
            ],
            "accountIds": [
                "http://example.com:10249/ServiceAccount/3354613317986071030"
            ],
            "success": true
        }
    }
]

^
|
```

Comment: Your JSON array is an array of response containers, not an array of responses.

Comment: Wops. Thanks. I'll revise.